# HashMap.containKey return wrong value

Tags: java

Iam  writing a java method which given a string of keywords will return a HashMap.
The key to the HashMap is an object of type subXMLdoc which I called docpart.
The value part of HashMap is an Array List of Term_with_Pos objects. My intention is to 
group all Term_with_Pos objects under the same "docpart" object. My question is why is that,
the following boolean expression is always equal to TRUE

```
          (ans.containsKey(docpart)== false)
```

SEE the method below:

```
    public static void termProximity (String qry, HashMap<subXMLdoc, 
                               ArrayList<Term_with_Pos>> ans
                                                      ) throws SQLException
    {
      // convert the string of keywords (qry) into a list of terms (query) 
      ArrayList<Term_with_Pos> query = convertQuery(qry);
      for (int i=0; i<query.size(); i++){
          ResultSet rs = DbaseManager.displayFreqTb2 (con, query.get(i).getTerm());
          while  (rs.next()){
             //create the xml element object.
             //This will serve as the key to the HashMap
            subXMLdoc docpart = new subXMLdoc (      rs.getString("docId"),
                                                rs.getInt("eTypeId") ,
                                               rs.getString("dewId")) ;
           //create a term with position object
          Term_with_Pos trm = new Term_with_Pos();
          trm.setTerm(rs.getString("trm"));
         // trm.setPosition(rs.getInt("pos")); 
         trm.setPosition(0); 

         if (ans.containsKey(docpart)==false){
             ArrayList<Term_with_Pos> postings = new ArrayList<>();
             postings.add(0,trm);
             ans.put(docpart,postings);
         } else{
            ArrayList<Term_with_Pos> postings = ans.get(docpart);
            int psize = postings.size();
            postings.add(psize,trm);
            ans.put(docpart,postings);
         }
      } // while
     rs.close();
     } // for  
   } // termProximity
```

I have already override the equal method as shown in the following class.

```
    public class subXMLdoc {
       private String docId ;
       private  int elmTypeId;    
       private String dewId ;

       public  subXMLdoc (String dcId, int nodeId, String dew){
         docId = dcId;
         elmTypeId =  nodeId ;    
         dewId = dew ;
       }   

       public int getNodeId (){ return elmTypeId;}
       public String getDew (){ return dewId;}
       public String getDocId (){ return docId;}  


       @Override
       public boolean equals(Object o){  
         if(!(o instanceof subXMLdoc))
           return false;
         subXMLdoc q = (subXMLdoc)o;
         return (this.docId.equals(q.getDocId())
                  && (this.elmTypeId == q.getNodeId()) && (this.dewId.equals(q.getDew())) );           
       }//equals
     }
```

Please help me identify why and how to solve the problem.

For a string qry = "monica lewinsky". The method returns the followings two columns output: The first column is the key of HashMap while the second column is the value part of the HashMap

```
      (3000, 11, 0.00.03.00.02.00)       (monica, 0)
      (1518000, 24, 0.00.03.02.00)       (monica, 0)
      (724000, 11, 0.00.03.00.13.00)     (monica, 0)
      (1360000, 11, 0.00.03.00.10.00)    (monica, 0)
      (3000, 11, 0.00.03.00.02.00)       (lewinsky, 0)
      (1294000, 28, 0.00.03.01.01)       (monica, 0)
      (420000, 24, 0.00.03.02.00)        (monica, 0)
      (976000, 28, 0.00.03.02.06)        (monica, 0)
      (1374000, 11, 0.00.03.00.31.00)    (monica, 0)
      (1360000, 12, 0.00.03.00.16.01)    (monica, 0)
      (1360000, 11, 0.00.03.00.16.00)    (monica, 0)
```

Notice that line 1 and line 5 have the same key  (3000, 11, 0.00.03.00.02.00) i.e docpart and therefore has to be merged into a single. The output therefore suppose to be

```
          (3000, 11, 0.00.03.00.02.00)       (monica, 0),  (lewinsky, 0)
          (1518000, 24, 0.00.03.02.00)        (monica, 0)
          (724000, 11, 0.00.03.00.13.00)     (monica, 0)
          (1360000, 11, 0.00.03.00.10.00)    (monica, 0)
          (1294000, 28, 0.00.03.01.01)       (monica, 0)
          (420000, 24, 0.00.03.02.00)         (monica, 0)
          (976000, 28, 0.00.03.02.06)         (monica, 0)
          (1374000, 11, 0.00.03.00.31.00)    (monica, 0)
          (1360000, 12, 0.00.03.00.16.01)    (monica, 0)
          (1360000, 11, 0.00.03.00.16.00)    (monica, 0)
```

Comment: `HashMap` works on the `hashCode` of the object, you've violated the `equals`/`hashCode` contract.

Answer (score 1):

You state:

> I have already override the equal method as shown in the following class.

You need to also override `hashCode`, especially for the key of a HashMap. Where do you do this?

Your hashCode should use the same fields that equals uses, and the contract is that if two objects are equal, their hashCodes **must** be identical, but the converse is not necessarily true -- two objects with the same hashCode can theoretically not be equal.

So if this is your equals:

```
   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o){  
     if(!(o instanceof subXMLdoc))
       return false;
     subXMLdoc q = (subXMLdoc)o;
     return (this.docId.equals(q.getDocId())
              && (this.elmTypeId == q.getNodeId()) 
              && (this.dewId.equals(q.getDew())) );           
   }
```

Then hashCode must use the docId, the elmTypeIt and the dewId fields to calculate its value.

---

For example (I cheated) but this is what Eclipse gave me for equals and hashCode, and it makes sense if you think about it:

```
   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
      final int prime = 31;
      int result = 1;
      result = prime * result + ((dewId == null) ? 0 : dewId.hashCode());
      result = prime * result + ((docId == null) ? 0 : docId.hashCode());
      result = prime * result + elmTypeId;
      return result;
   }
   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (this == obj)
         return true;
      if (obj == null)
         return false;
      if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
         return false;
      SubXmlDoc other = (SubXmlDoc) obj;
      if (dewId == null) {
         if (other.dewId != null)
            return false;
      } else if (!dewId.equals(other.dewId))
         return false;
      if (docId == null) {
         if (other.docId != null)
            return false;
      } else if (!docId.equals(other.docId))
         return false;
      if (elmTypeId != other.elmTypeId)
         return false;
      return true;
   }
```

---

As an aside, please note also that your code should comply with Java naming conventions to avoid fooling others. Class names should begin with an upper case letter, and all non-constant names should use camel case. So your class name should be `"SubXmlDoc"`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I Want to compute the proximity of the keywords in the given string  value. Please how do I override the hashCode.

Comment: @user3422243: see edit to answer. The examples I see often use powers of prime numbers to try to increase the separations of the hash boxes.

Comment: @user3422243: note also that your code should comply with Java naming conventions to avoid fooling others. Class names should begin with an upper case letter, and all non-constant names should use camel case. So your class name should be `"SubXmlDoc"`.

Comment: It is typo s is small letter  For a string qry = "monica lewinsky" the output i often get is

Comment: line 1.  (3000, 11, 0.00.03.00.02.00)  (monica, 0)
line 2.  (1518000, 24, 0.00.03.02.00)  (monica, 0)
line 3.  (724000, 11, 0.00.03.00.13.00)  (monica, 0)
line 4. (1360000, 11, 0.00.03.00.10.00)  (monica, 0)
line 5. (3000, 11, 0.00.03.00.02.00)  (lewinsky, 0)
6. (1294000, 28, 0.00.03.01.01)  (monica, 0)
7. (420000, 24, 0.00.03.02.00)  (monica, 0)
line 8. (976000, 28, 0.00.03.02.06)  (monica, 0)
line 9.  (1374000, 11, 0.00.03.00.31.00)  (monica, 0)
line 10. (1360000, 12, 0.00.03.00.16.01)  (monica, 0)
line 11.  (1360000, 11, 0.00.03.00.16.00)  (monica, 0)

Comment: line 1  and line 5 are suppose to be merged into a single line because they have the same (3000, 11, 0.00.03.00.02.00)

Comment: @user3422243: what the heck is all this unreadable junk you're posting in comments?

Comment: The method work after putting the override hascode method. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `hashCode()` method in you class. `HashMap` use `hashCode` of your object. You must override both `equals()` and `hashCode()` here.